# Place lightning-input message next to element

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I'm using this one to display

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
      <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
          <span class="slds-form-element__label cxd-toggle__label-medium">Block List</span>
          <input type="checkbox" 
            name="cxdBlockCB" 
            onchange={unlockCheckboxesRelaxed}
            checked={relaxedChecked}
            disabled={relaxedDisabled}  
            />
          <span class="slds-checkbox_faux_container">
            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
            <!-- <span class="slds-checkbox_on">Active</span>
            <span class="slds-checkbox_off">Inactive</span> -->
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
```

is it possible to show let's say 'Active' next to the `input` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom CSS to make this work. use the `float` CSS attribute as follows:

```
<label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
        <span class="slds-form-element__label cxd-toggle__label-medium">Block List</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cxdBlockCB" onchange={unlockCheckboxesRelaxed} checked={relaxedChecked} disabled={relaxedDisabled} />
        <span class="slds-checkbox_faux_container" style="float: left;">
                <span class="slds-checkbox_faux" style="float: left;"></span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_on" style="float: right; margin: 6px;">Active</span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_off" style="float: right; margin: 6px;">Inactive</span>
        </span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-assistive-text">Toggle</span>
</label>
```

Output: [image]